# Android HashMap overwrite keys?

Tags: java, android, hashmap

I have this simple Code

```
public static HashMap<String, String> FixDataBeforeSenddd(final ImageManager image1,
                                                          final ImageManager image2,
                                                          final ImageManager image3,
                                                          final ImageManager video)
{
    int index = 1;
    boolean hasChanged = false;
    HashMap<String, String> hash = new HashMap<String, String>();
    ArrayList<ImageManager> list = new ArrayList<ImageManager>();
    list.add(image1);
    list.add(image2);
    list.add(image3);
    for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++)
        if (list.get(i).getHasChanged() == true)
            hasChanged = true;
    if (hasChanged == true)
        for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++)
            if (list.get(i).getHasImage())
            {
                hash.put(index + "", list.get(i).getFilePath());
                index++;
            }
    if (video.getHasChanged() == true)
        if (video.getHasImage() == true)
        {
            hash.put("videoImage", video.getVideoThumlPath());
            hash.put("video", video.getVideoFilePath());
        }
    return hash;// mh;
}
```

Now the Problem is that the every hash.put is overwriting an existing Key, Lets assume that I have images in every imageManager object So the first for loop the result should be like this:

```
   {"1"="SomePath...","2"="SomePath...","3"="SomePath...",//end for loop,"video"="SomePath","videoImage"="SomePath"}
```

but the actual result are:

```
"video"="SomePath","videoImage"="SomePath"
```

and id the video ImageManager is empty but not the others the result is:
"3"="SomePath..."

why does is overwrite a different keys??

***EDIT***

while i was debugging I noticed that the key that was overwritten going into the "next" cell using Watcher

Comment: Make the for loop curly braces correctly

Comment: check the hasChanged variable. May be your hasChanged variable is false thats why hashmap doesnot contains
    {"1"="SomePath...","2"="SomePath...","3"="SomePath...",

Comment: I need hasChange to be true even if only one image has changed, I ran the code in debug, it allways true, and i can see while in debug mode that the Keys are being overwritten

Comment: I really don't understand this question or what you are trying to do.

Comment: Lets say that I have 4 slot for 4 images on my server. I want to fill the slots one by one. now, I have been asked to upload a form with one image at slot 1, and upload the other 3 seperetly, so 3 uploads for 3 left slots, when I pull them out of the server, sort of "EDIT" mode to the form, I want to set them in the right slot. For example lets say that this Zeros are the imageView that the user see 0000 now, the user has selected images in 1010 (the most right zero is the "videoImage"), so what I need to send to the server is slot 1, slot 2. and when the user enters EDIT it will be shown 0110

Answer (score 0):

`hasChanged` will always be set to the value of the last item in the list. If you want to set `hasChanged` to true if *any* of the list items has changed, change your for loop to:

```
for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
    if (list.get(i).getHasChanged()) {
        hasChanged |= true;
    }
}
```

Also added braces to improve readability.

Comment: I need the hasChange to be always true if even one image has been set to the object.

Comment: The above for loop will do that. `|=` is shorthand for `hasChanged = hasChanged || true`, so if any of the images in the lest is marked as changed, `hasChanged` will be true.

Comment: but the problem is not the hasChange